Right aligning signature in a letter using KOMA-script
I'm using Letter Template for DIN A4 from Overleaf. At the bottom of the letter are closing and signature. I'd like closing to be aligned left and the signature aligned right.
Is it even possible to separate closing and signature?

Main LaTeX file brief.tex (German for 'letter'):
%%
% German Latex Letter Template 
% Use if you want to crate a Letter in DIN A4. You can use it in English and German 
% as well, just set language at begining of plain text.
% Created by Jan Boelmann @ Nov. 2016 Jan.boelmann@live.de
%%

\documentclass[
    sender,
    paper=a4,
    version=last,
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV=13,
    BCOR=0mm]{scrlttr2}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Set Font: sans serif Latin Modern
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Set Page layout:
\usepackage{changepage}
%\changepage{text height}{text width}{even-side margin}
%{odd-side margin}{column sep.}
%{topmargin}{headheight}{headsep}{footskip}
\changepage{+3cm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{-5cm}
\LoadLetterOption{sender}

\begin{document}
% Set Appendix text at very end (dubble point will be set automatically)
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Appendix}
% subject, date, place:
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject: This is an Example}
\setkomavar{date}{den 14. November 2016}
\setkomavar{place}{Bremen}


% Set recipient of letter
\begin{letter}{
    Recipient name \\
    Company SoUndSo\\
    What ever Street\\
    12345 ExampleCity
}
\opening{Dear Recipient}

% Write here your Letter text. You can choose here the language for typeset. ("english", or "ngerman")
\selectlanguage{english}
%\parindent2mm
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,


%\selectlanguage{english}%Choose language for closing text
\closing{kind regards} % use "Mit freundlich Grüßen" i.e. 
\encl{annex}
% end of letter
\end{letter}

\end{document}


Letter options file sender.lco:

%%
% German Latex Letter Template 
% Use if you want to crate a Letter in DIN A4. You can use it in English and German 
% as well, just set language at begining of plain text.
% Created by Jan Boelmann @ Nov. 2016 Jan.boelmann@live.de
%%

\ProvidesFile{sender.lco}[letter-class-option file]

% symbols: Mobilephone, Phone, E-Mail
\RequirePackage{marvosym}

% Text of this document (sender.lco) is UTF-8 encoded
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% if yu wnat some colors...
\RequirePackage{color}


% see Koma script for more detailed descriptions
% comment or delate if not needed
\KOMAoptions{
    foldmarks=true,
    fromalign=right,
    footsepline=off,
    fromurl=off,
    fromemail=true,
    fromfax=off,
    fromphone=true,
    frommobilephone=true,
}



% You can define colors here like this...
%\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}
%\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}


% Sender data:
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Telefon~]{+49\,123\,1234567}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}[\Mobilefone~]{+49\,123\,1234567}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter~]{test@testmail.com}
%\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{http://test.de}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Sender Name, Example Street 123 D, 12345 ExampleCity}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sender Name\\Example Street 123 D\\12345 ExampleCity}



% optical stuff:
\setkomafont{fromname}{\bfseries\color{black}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromrule}{\color{black}}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\rmfamily\mdseries\slshape\color{black}}
% maybe in blue...
%\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\rmfamily\mdseries\slshape\color{myblue}}
\setkomafont{addressee}{\small}


\setkomavar{signature}{Sender Name}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

% define vertical distance for signature
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{1.8cm}
\endinput



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Added code from Overleaf.

You've added the same file twice … For the future, I would recommend to not add sender.lco to the question, but copy the relevant content or that file or just add a \setkomavar{fromname}{…} resp. \setkomavar{signature}{…} to the MWE of the document. One file MWEs are always preferred.

Off-topic: Instead of \parskip3mm you should either use option parskip or command \setparsizes as documented in the KOMA-Script manuals. BTW: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} shouldn't be needed for a very long time. And note, that the comment to \changepage could be somehow misleading. The set page layout in this case does not mean that the command sets, e.g., text height to the given value, but adds the given value to the existing setting. Subjectively, I find geometry easier or more manageable.

Thank you for these comments, @cabohah. I fixed the second file. The template was created 8 years ago but it's layout was still closest to what I needed. Writing my thesis was much easier than writing a simple letter.

Set the signature right-aligned inside a box of appropriate width:
% Set signature flush right with the text block.
\setkomavar{signature}{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{Who Cares}}


